# WP_Query don't working with fixed post_id and term_taxonomy

Tags: wp-query

I don't know why but WP_Query don't working with fixed post_id and term_taxonomy. I have a WP_Query what is working fine without fixed post id (`'p' => 251`)

But it isn't "read" the tax_query when the post_id is set.

The Query:

```
$args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'terms'    => '11',
                'field'    => 'term_id'

            ),
        ),
        'p' => 231,
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(

            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'value' => $date_from,
                'compare' => '>='

            ),

            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'value' => $date_till,
                'compare' => '<='
            )

        )

    );
```

The SQL code without post_id:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (12) ) AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '0' ) AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'date' AND mt1.meta_value <= 'null' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'events' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

And the SQL code with post_id:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID = 231 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '0' ) AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'date' AND mt1.meta_value <= 'null' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'events' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I spend hours to solve this problem, but I don't fine solution yet...

**EDIT**: Oh my God I found the solution!

```
$args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'terms'    => '11',
                'field'    => 'term_id'

            ),
        ),
        'post__in' => array(231), //instead of 'p'
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(

            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'value' => $date_from,
                'compare' => '>='

            ),

            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'value' => $date_till,
                'compare' => '<='
            )

        )

    );
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it as correct rather than pasting it into your question, as this keeps the site format tidy.  Thanks.

Comment: Why use a complex `WP_Query` if you already know the `post_id` ? Why not `get_post( $post_id )` to get the post object?

Comment: This is just an example. :)  The post_id is coming through ajax request in the live site.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you described is how WordPress works by design, if you provide a `'p'` parameter, then `'tax_query'` is ignored,  see inside this [`else` statment in wp-includes/query.php:L1643](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1643), this is where `'tax_query'` is processed and added to the SQL statement, and this only happens if this [`if` (line 1634)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1634) is skipped.